# materialize-css in react component blocks still overlap

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I have 2 issues here:

The  text goes behind the image when resizing the screen and it gets too small.

The logo image bumps just a little to the right when I start to resize the screen going from large to small (happens early on).

I am using materialize-css in my react app.

```
<nav>
        <div className='nav-wrapper'
          style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}>
          <img
            className='round logo-img brand-logo left responsive-img col s2'
            style={{maxHeight:'100%', display:'block'}}
            src={'../../../public/favicon.ico'}>
            </img>
        <h4
          className='col s10 right'
          style={{whiteSpace:'nowrap', display:'block'}}
          >
          COMPANY NAME
        </h4>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Do not use UI frameworks like materialize-css with react. reason: https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-mix-jquery-and-react-cit77t20z02j5fq536wlyiwtk try material-ui instead